# How to export google sheet as Excel/CSV and Overwrite Existing File

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an app script to export one of the Google sheets as Excel or CSV but I want it to overwrite existing exported file and not create a new file (It piles up on my downloads folder and I have apps that needs the file in same static file name.

I can't find an option to do this, so far the parameters of export URL doesn't have overwrite feature. Is this possible in App Script?

```
function ExprtMe()
{  
  var SheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  ShtURL = SheetApp.getUrl();
  ShtID = SheetApp.getId();
  ShtGID = SheetApp.getSheetId();
  var url = ShtURL.toString().replace("/edit", "/export?format=xlsx&gid=" + ShtGID);
  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, overwriting an existing file in your local machine is not possible through App Script.

It is only possible to overwrite a file using App Script if the file is in your Drive by using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js) and `update()` method.

I have two suggestions for you to be able to overwrite existing file while downloading in Google Chrome.

1. `You can change chrome's setting for downloading file`

- By default, Chrome will automatically save all files to the Downloads folder without asking the user for confirmation. There is a setting on chrome that prompt user download confirmation. You can do that by following these [steps](https://windowsreport.com/download-overwrite-existing-files/)

2. `Use third-party extensions`

- There are several Chrome extension you can install if you want to overwrite existing files while downloading.

Comment: Thanks George, that makes sense considering security measures Google has to implement.

Comment: Welcome Jay, I'm glad I was able to help.